# What's the current status of migration-assistant?

Tags: installation, ubiquity

I've never noticed the [migration assistant](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MigrationAssistant) I used to see when installing older versions of Ubuntu. Is it just hidden inside Ubiquity, or is it gone completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still there, and it will only appear if you actually have files/settings that are detected for migration.

Comment: This is no longer true. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTEwOTg

Answer (score 2):

The Migration Assistant is still there. See
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/natty/ubiquity/natty/files/head:/ubiquity/plugins/

The Migration Assistant file was last modified in December 2010.

Comment: How should I use it during installation though?